# Displaying Data from other Models by calling them within a standard Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, embedding

Say I have 2 models - Posts and Questions. Is there a way to allow Questions to be included within the main Post text? For example, could I create a syntax that will include a Question at a specified point in Post's text? (I could use Nested forms to add a Question after a Post, but I want to include a Question within the post.)

This would similar to Wordpress's [shortcodes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API), but for including my own data instead of embedding from other sites.

Here's an **example**:

Question 5:

#### Why did the chicken cross the road?

Form for Post 2 text:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor...
[include question.id=5]
...consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

Post 2 view:

> Lorem ipsum dolor...
>
> #### Why did the chicken cross the road?
>
> ...consectetur adipiscing elit.

**Possible Solution:**
Scan the Post text in the controller looking for special syntax, and then delete that text and use it to create (or find) a Question. Is there a simpler solution or a gem that would help with this?

**PS**
This could also be used to include simple repeated text within a post. You could create a text template and then call it within a form (as in the above example).

Comment: I also did it for article , where I wanted to embed some images and clips. I did it like you suggested, I looked for the placeholders inside my article and replaced it with the images I wanted. I would also like to know if there is some Gem that will do it for me.

Comment: @obenda, I didn't see anything exactly like that when browsing through the Ruby Toolbox, though there is Microformats for semantic markup, and Markdown converters (like Redcarpet) which convert text before displaying them. Maybe one of them could be adapted for this purpose though...

Comment: @obenda btw, you can embed images with image tags (and marking the text html_safe) and videos with iframes.

Comment: in theory i could do the same thing and create a view for the questions and embed them in an iframe. but idk if that makes sense..

Answer (score 0):

I realized instead of doing it directly, you can just mark an area in the Post's text, and then use javascript to move up a matching Question when it's displayed.